# Match parent's parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `AppBarLayout` (height set to `wrap_content`) with a `Toolbar` and a toolbar-shaped button (made with a `CoordinatorLayout`) below it inside. When the button is clicked, I want to make it be `gone` and make another view (a `RecyclerView`) `visible` which would fill the whole screen (`match_parent` for the main `CoordinatorLayout`, which is the parent of the `AppBarLayout`). When I make it `visible` with `match_parent`, the view does not occupy the whole screen, just approximately half of it.

Is there any "match parent's parent" size constant for views whose parent is set to `wrap_content`?

Before clicking the button:
[Before clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XujNl.png)

After clicking the button:
[After clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qhAI.png)

**Code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PedidosActivity">

    <!-- Screen content below toolbar -->
    .
    .
    .
    <!-- End of screen content -->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarPedidos"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />


            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/btnLineaLayout"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLinea"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/linea"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24"
                    android:tint="@android:color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:visibility="visible" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**PS:** Someone please change the links to images, I don't have enough reputation.

**PS 2:** I know one way of achieving this would be to set programmatically the `AppBarLayout`'s height to `match_parent` but it seems "dirty" and not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the `RelativeLayout` in your code. But when you do it like this the `RelativeLayout` should cover the whole screen

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PedidosActivity">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    </RelativeLayout>

.
.
.
```